# Issue adding sub category programmatically

Tags: php, categories, woocommerce-offtopic

i am trying to insert products from an array.
The product is successfully created and the values are inserted normally except the sub-category.
The issue here is that the subcategory is registered as top level (no parent) or it's not registered at all.
Anyone have any idea on what i am missing here ?

Outside from function

```
        $parent_cat_a= term_exists($myproduct['12'], 'category');
        $parent_cat_a_id= $parent_term_a['term_id'];
        eisagwghproion($myproductssimple);
```

Inside function

```
 $product_to_create = array(
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status' => "publish",
            'post_title' => $myproduct['6'], 
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_date' => $myproduct['22'],
            'post_parent' => '',
            'post_type' => "product",
                    );
                $post_id= wp_insert_post($product_to_create, true);
                if (!$post_id) //
                {
                    return false;
                }            
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_price', $myproduct['17']);
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_regular_price', $myproduct['17']);
                update_post_meta($post_id, '_sku', $myproduct['2'] );
                wp_set_object_terms($post_id, 'simple', 'product_type');

                                  if(strlen($myproduct['13']) > 1){
                    $parent_cat_a = term_exists($myproduct['13'], 'product_cat');
                    if($parent_cat_a !== null) //εαν υπαρχει η υπο κατηγορια
                        {
                            wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $myproduct['13'] , 'product_cat');
                        }
                        else //εαν δεν υπάρχει η υπο κατηγορια
                        {
                            $parent_cat_a_id = $parent_cat_a['term_id'];  
                            wp_insert_term(
                                $myproduct['13'], // the term 
                                'product_cat', // the taxonomy
                                array(
                                'slug' => $myproduct['13'],
                                'parent'=> $parent_cat_a_id
                                )
                            );
                            wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $myproduct['13'] , 'product_cat');
                        }
                    }
                    else{wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $myproduct['12'] , 'product_cat');}
```

Answer (score 0):

with this code we add a new main category

```php
wp_insert_term( 'My New Category', 'product_cat', array('parent' => 0));
```

then knowing the category parent id we can add a sub category like so

```php
wp_insert_term( 'My New Sub-category', 'product_cat', array('parent' => 72));
```

this is more or less what you have, but when I run the function get_terms I receive an array with two values, this means your variable $parent_cat_a would be something like this

```php
Array
(
    [term_id] => 74
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 74
)
```

This means when you are calling $parent_cat_a, you arent recieving the parent id, you are just putting an array with more than one choice, worpress will not know how to use it, you should be calling $parent_cat_a['term_id']

so where you have

```php
$parent_cat_a = term_exists($myproduct['13'], 'product_cat');
```

I would replace it with

```php
$parent_cat_aa = term_exists($myproduct['13'], 'product_cat');
$parent_cat_a = $parent_cat_aa['term_id'];
```

this probably will put your code to work, one more thing, like the first code above, inside the wp_insert_term() before parent you don't need the slug, wordpress will put it for you, will check the category name and make a slug without spaces. its safer once you are putting the exactly same name.